# Problemas con mensajes de alerta en python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Al ingresar a una página web con selenium webdriver me aparece siempre esta ventana de alerta, para ingresar mi usuario, contraseña e ingresar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mensaje no permite seleccionar el `"inspeccionar"`, así que he estando intentando interactuar con este cuadro emergente a través de estas funciones:

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.send_keys('Some text to send')
alert.accept()
```

Pero Python siempre me muestra el mismo error: `Message: no such alert`

Como si no fuera un mensaje de alerta lo que aparece en la ventana, entonces como puedo hacer entonces para rellenar este cuadro emergente con mi usuario y contraseña, y luego darle aceptar?

Comment: Es posible que el alert aún no exista cuando se ejecuta  `driver.switch_to.alert `, prueba a incorporar un tiempo de espera, algo como     `WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())`

Comment: Ya también intenté agregar el tiempo de espera y no funcionó, igual el mensaje de la ventana aparece justo cuando se intenta ingresar a la página web, sin ningún retardo

Comment: Parece que no se trata de un *alert nativo del navegador*, sino de un *custom-prompt*, fíjate si esa *alerta* es en realidad un *div* que parece un *prompt* gracias a *css*. Si no es el caso, puedes utilizar *pyautogui* para hacer el *loggin* y luego continuar con *selenium*.

Comment: @tecnobillo el problema es que con pyautogui no se puede ejecutar en segundo plano, o si? he intentado con esta librería y efectivamente escribe sobre la ventana en las coordenadas especificadas, pero para que esto funcione tiene que estar parado en la ventana de interés al ejecutar el script, o sabes como puedo ejecutarlo en segundo plano?
Y como verifico lo de la alerta que me dices si de pronto es un div que parece un promt?

Comment: No puede ejecutarse en segundo plano con *pyautogui*, una solución sería que el navegador esté en unas coordenadas fuera del monitor. Si quieres comparte la *url* de la página y le echo un vistazo cuando pueda. Saludos.

Comment: Mira el link de una página que tiene un cuadro de logueo como el que digo http://www.advancedhtml.co.uk/password/   encontré que para este tipo de logueos se puede poner directamente en el link http://www.usuario:contraseña@la dirección de la página, pero esta opción para mi no funciona porque es una página corporativa que no admite cambiar la url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta ventana de login se produce por culpa del .htaccess, al intentar acceder a una zona restringida. Esta ventana se genera mucho antes de que el navegador genere el código HTML, por eso Selenium no puede actuar dado que aún no se ha cargado la página.
Una posible solución sería crear un Thread con selenium y usar un time.sleep(3 seg) y seguidamente ejecutar otro Thread con pyautogui para el registro.

1.- Crear el `main` y crear los dos `Threads`.

2.- Crear un `Thread` con selenium que incluya un `Time.sleep()` #Con esto le dará tiempo a que el pyautogui pueda ejecutarse y simular el registro#

3.- Crear un `Thread` con `pyautogui`

4.- Run del `Thread` del selenium y seguidamente el Run del `Thread` con pyautogui

Espero que funcione. Ya nos contarás.

Comment: Ya había intentado esa combinación con selenium y pyatogui que mencionas, pero sigue siendo un problema que pyautogui no pueda ejecutarse en segundo plano. ¿Sabes como puedo hacer para que este funcione en segundo plano?

Comment: Creo que una buena opción sería usar el multiproceso, te dejo un link donde lo explica: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html a ver si con esto hay suerte

Comment: Otra opción sería ejecutar un proceso de python desde python: execfile(r'C:\otro_proceso.py')

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizar *selenium* y *pyautogui* es una solución (como se explica en la respuesta anterior), pero sigue siendo un problema no poder ejecutar *pyautogui* en segundo plano, lo único que se me ocurre es ocultar el navegador posicionándolo fuera de las dimensiones del monitor:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

x_size, y_size = pyautogui.size()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument(f'--window-position=-{x_size},-{y_size}')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--window-size={x_size},{y_size}')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

De esta manera el navegador tiene las mismas dimensiones que el monitor pero se encuentra en una posición tal que es invisible al usuario.

Sigue apareciendo el icono del navegador en la barra de tareas, y si quieres introducir datos en el *prompt* que muestra la página tendrías que mover el cursor a dicha posición.

**NOTA:**

Después de realizar el *loggin* podrías ocultar el *icono del navegador de la barra de tareas* listando los procesos activos y usando la utilidad [cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/).

No se si te servirá. Un saludo.